# MySQL query which will give me a sum of multiple rows and total number of rows from 2 tables for each year

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables, table damage and table policy. I want to create a query which will return total number of damages, sum of damage costs, total number of policies and sum of profits for each year(2019,2020 and 2021).

this is what I have so far, any help is well appreciated.

```
create table damage(
 damageID mediumint NOT NULL auto_increment,
 damage_cost int(10),
 year1 year,
 PRIMARY KEY (damageID)
);

create table policy(
policyID mediumint NOT NULL auto_increment,
profit int(10),
year2 year,
PRIMARY KEY (policyID)
);

insert into damage values(1, 1000, 2019);
insert into damage values(2, 200, 2019);
insert into damage values(3, 100, 2019);

insert into damage values(4, 10, 2020);
insert into damage values(5, 400, 2020);
insert into damage values(6, 800, 2020);

insert into damage values(7, 12, 2021);
insert into damage values(8, 55, 2021);
insert into steta values(9, 22, 2021);

insert into policy values(1, 5, 2019);
insert into policy  values(2, 23, 2019);
insert into policy  values(3, 99, 2019);

insert into policy values(4, 510, 2020);
insert into policy values(5, 35, 2020);
insert into policy values(6, 52, 2020);

insert into policy values(7, 4, 2021);
insert into policy values(8, 23, 2021);
insert into policy values(9, 198, 2021);

select 
    count(damageID) as NumberOfDamages, 
    sum(damage_cost) sumOfDamages, 
    count(policyID) as NumberOfPolicies, 
    sum(profit) as sumOfProfits, 
    year(year1) as years
```

Comment: The query is missing the table names and joining criteria.

Comment: You're also missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Are the two tables related to each other? There doesn't seem to be a foreign key. Shouldn't the `damage` table have a `policyID` column to say which policy the damage was from?

Comment: If they're not related, do two separate queries and combine them with `UNION` to get everything in a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're looking for

```
with 
    damage_agg as (
        select 
            year,
            count(damageID) as NumberOfDamages, 
            sum(damage_cost) sumOfDamages
        from 
            damage
        group by 
            year
    ),
    policy_agg as (
        select
            year,
            count(policyID) as NumberOfPolicies, 
            sum(profit) as sumOfProfits
        from
            policy 
        group by
            year
    )
select
    *
from
    damage_agg
    full outer join
    policy_agg on policy_agg.year = damage_agg.year
/
```